# Selecting and clicking dropdown menu items with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer, browser-automation

I need to select and then click a dropdown menu item with puppeteer to log out.

The menu requires a mouse be hovered over it to drop down rather than click.

When I choose to copy selector for dropdown menu area I get one of two things.

```
#ds-desktop-nav-main > div > div > ul.ds-nav-toolbar > li.ds-btn-group.ds-dropdown-group.ds-my-xxx-dropdown.show-logged-in > a > span
```

or

```
#ds-desktop-nav-main > div > div > ul.ds-nav-toolbar > li.ds-btn-group.ds-dropdown-group.ds-my-xxx-dropdown.show-logged-in > a
```

the selector for logout button is:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" class="ga-tracking" data-ga-action="user" data-ga-category="main_nav" data-ga-label="LOGOUT">Logout</a>
```

the whole thing is stored in a UL class with LI elements

Here is the HTML for the element you need to hover over to initiate dropdown.

```
<a href="/users/current" class="ga-tracking" data-ga-category="main_nav" data-ga-action="user" data-ga-label="PROFILE"><span class="user-icon"></span></a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The website does not belong to me so I cannot add anything to it.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is call `page.hover('some-selector')` (official example is [here](https://github.com/checkly/puppeteer-examples/blob/master/1.%20basics/hover.js))

So in your case:

```
page.hover('a[href="/users/sign_out"]')
```

You can use the crazy nested selector but I would rather go for something that will most likely not change in the near future.

You can read more about attribute selectors [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/).